# Allocate places according to distance

Tags: database, math

As an over-simplified example I have a list of events that have a maximum attendance:

```
 event    | places
===================
 event_A  |   1
 event_B  |   2
 event_C  |   1
```

And a list of attendees with the distance to the events:

```
 attendee    | event_A dist | event_B dist | event_C dist
==========================================================
 attendee_1  |      12      |      15      |      12      
 attendee_2  |      11      |      15      |      11
 attendee_3  |      10      |      11      |      12
```

Can anyone suggest a simple method to produce a set of options providing the best case allocations based on shortest total distance and on shortest mean distance?

I currently have the data held in Oracle Spatial database, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: If each attendee should be matched to exactly one event, then this looks like a weighted perfect matching. You can use the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to compute that matching. I'm unsure what you mean by total and mean distance in this context.

Comment: @MvG A bit of clarification; in my actual data there will be more places than attendees, so the events do not have to be full, but they cannot be "over-full". For the possible solutions I'd like 2; one showing the lowest total distance (i.e. sum of all attendees' distances), the other showing the mean distance (i.e. sum of all attendees' distances / No. of attendees).

Comment: You indicate that you want two different solutions, but the difference to me appears to be only what you show to the user. What is the global (i.e. not event-specific) objective you try to optimize? I'd have thought you'd likely want to minimize the sum of all distances traveled, for all attendees and all events. Anything optimizing means will be a lot trickier to compute and probably not very reasonable either.

Comment: @MvG You are correct, I'm not interested in all the solutions, I think the most relevant solution is as you say, the one that minimizes the sum of all distances travelled. However I've also been asked to provide the lowest mean distance as well, but if this isn't easily possible I don't mind excluding it.

Answer (score 0):

I currently understand your problem as follows:

- Each atendee should be assigned to exactly one event
- Each event has a limit as to how many atendees are assigned to it
- Underfull or even empty events are no problem
- Each assignment between an event and an atendee corresponds to a given distance
- You want to minimize the overall distance for all assignments
- You might want to print the result not using sums but using means

Based on this interpretation, I suggest the following algorithm:

1. Create a complete bipartite graph, with nodes in partition *A* for atendees and nodes in partition *B* for places in events. So every atendee corresponds to one node, and every event corresponds to as many nodes as it has places. All atendees are connected to all event nodes with the distance as the edge cost.

   At this point your problem corresponds to a [general assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), with “agents” corresponding to your event places, and “tasks” corresponding to your atendees. Every atendee must be covered, but not every event place must be used.
2. Add dummy attendees to allow a perfect matching. Simply sum up all the places, subtract from that the number of actual atendees. For the difference, create as many atendee nodes, with distance zero to all the event nodes.

   By making both partitions equal in size, you are now in the domain of the more common [linear assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).
3. Use the [hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to compute a minimal cost assignment. Perhaps you can think of some simplifications which make use of the fact that you have many equivalent nodes, i.e. places for the same event and all those dummy atendees.

All of this should probably be done in application code, not in the data base. So I'd rather tag this [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm). You'll need to pull the full cost matrix from the database to provide costs for your edges.